# Lift morphism along a functor

Tags: category-theory

Let $(\mathcal{C}, F)$ be a pair consisting of a (locally small) category $\mathcal{C}$ and a functor $F \colon \mathcal{C} \to \mathbf{Set}$ satisfying the following properties:

1. F is faithful.
2. $\mathcal{C}$ is complete and $F$ is continuous.
3. $\mathcal{C}$ admits filtered colimits and $F$ commutes with them.
4. $F$ reflects isomorphism.

Let $A,B,C$ be objects in $\mathcal{C}$ an let $f \colon A \to B$ and $g \colon C \to B$ be two arrows such that $g$ is a monomorphism.

Now suppose there is a map $\tilde{h} \colon FA \to FC$ such that
$$ Ff = Fg \circ \tilde{h}.$$

Is there a morphism $h \colon A \to C$ such that $Fh = \tilde{h}$ and $f = gh$?

The reason for this question is lemma 6.15.4 (tag 007P) of the Stacks Project. Following the proof of the lemma I understand why $FA = F(A \times_B C)$. Then it states that $A = A \times_B C$ since $F$ reflects isomorphisms. But why is the canonical isomorphism in the image of $F$. If the answer above is yes, then this is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the diagram of sets that results as the image of the pullback $A \overset{s}\leftarrow P \overset{r}\to C$ of $f,g$:
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
FP &\overset{Fr}\to & FC \\
_{Fs}\downarrow & \nearrow & \downarrow_{Fg} \\
FA &\underset{Ff}\to & FB
\end{array}
$$
where the "lifting" is the $\tilde h$ of your post; from this it's easy to see that $Fs$ is invertible, and so is $s$ because $F$ reflects isomorphisms; the image under $F$ of this pair of isomorphisms is an isomorphism $FP\cong FA$. $s$ is unique with this property, and so is its inverse.

All in all, your $h$ is just $rs^{-1}$ (the fact that $F$ is faithful has been secretly used).

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot! 
What do you mean by "the fact that F is faithful has been secretly used"?

Comment: I'm sure at some point you have to use the fact that $F$ is faithful, but I was too tired yesterday to make precise where exactly :-)